# Generate unique serial number each day

Tags: sql, serialization, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 application that needs to create a unique serial number that restarts every day at `1`. So the table has a compound primary key using Julian date and the serial number. I'll have a stored procedure to find the next serial number - how do I guarantee that two users won't get the same number?

Does this work?

```
INSERT INTO tbl_test (sn1, sn2) 
VALUES (1, (SELECT isnull(max(sn2) + 1,1) 
            FROM   tbl_test 
            WHERE  sn1 = 1))
```

And what is the best way to test the code to verify that it will work correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need an id that restarts on each day?  You can calculate it on the fly when you need it:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by cast(CreatedAt as date) order by id) as DayId
from table t;
```

If you do want to have guarantees, I would suggest that you use a sequence.  But, alas, you are using SQL Server 2008 so you don't have access to that.  Otherwise, use a trigger.

I don't think your method will work for two users that make the request at "exactly" the same time.

Comment: The serial number has to restart each day because a bunch of people that earn a lot more than I do say so. Push back on that decision is not an option. Can you please explain how a trigger would solve the problem? thanks.